# Example for a theorem on weakly convergent sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

In the lecture we had the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a Banachspace and let $x_k\rightarrow x$ strongly in $X$ and $x_k'\rightarrow x'$ weakly* in $X'$
>
> $\Rightarrow$ $x_k'(x_k)\rightarrow x'(x)$ for $k\rightarrow \infty$. Same goes for $x_k\rightarrow x$ weakly in $X$ and $x_k'\rightarrow x'$ strongly in $X'$

Since it had been specified that at least one of the two sequences has to converge strongly, I suppose that $x_k'(x_k)\rightarrow x'(x)$ for $k\rightarrow\infty$ is not true, if $x_k'\rightarrow x'$ weakly* in $X'$ and $x_k\rightarrow x$ weakly in $X$. What would be an example of that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, and identify it with its dual. Let $e_k$ be the $k^{\text{th}}$ "standard" unit vector, and $x_k = x_k' = e_k$. Then $x_k \to 0$ and $x_k' \to 0$ weakly, but $\langle x_k', x_k\rangle = 1 \neq \langle 0, 0\rangle$.